# Is the Watch Dogs Complete Bundle paying twice for the same DLCs?

Tags: steam, watch-dogs

Is the [Watch_Dogs Complete Bundle](https://store.steampowered.com/sub/85571/) (Base, Season Pass, Bad Blood, Conspiracy & Access Granted) double charging for the same things?

The [Watch_Dogs Wiki](https://watchdogs.fandom.com/wiki/Season_Pass_(Watch_Dogs)) says that the Season Pass, is already Bad Blood, Conspiracy & Access Granted, plus a few additional things.

Is that wrong, or am I actually saving anything if I buy the Complete version instead of just Base and Season Pass?

Answer (score 3):

It's basically the same price as buying everything standalone. I've seen this being drive by multiple games when the season pass is actually a "DLC" itself rather than just a bundle.

This is most likely due to third party keys being involved. Don't worry, you're not paying twice for it.

Comment: So, Season Pass alone doesn't get me the other things in the Complete collection, you're saying? ... Or that the further price reduction from being a Bundle, cancels out the price of the Season Pass?

Comment: @Malady No, it gets you the very same things.

Comment: So, there's no difference between Complete and Base + Season Pass, you're saying?

Comment: @Malady Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Buy just the Season Pass and the Base Game. It's usually cheaper than buying the individual DLCs, and you get Everything. The Season Pass has some unique items.

Also, if you buy the Pass, Steam marks EVERYTHING as being in your library, so you're good.

Never buy them individually. Always go for a bundle.

The Complete Bundle's group savings isn't the whole cost of the Season Pass, presumably made so you're paying for the unique items that are in the Season Pass, such as the "Untouchable pack" instead of getting them for free.